# How to conditionally copy a drop down in google-sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a drop down with a few options.

I want to conditionally copy the drop down to the following line. Keeping the selected value and its options.

I have tried:

`=IF(Placements!$B3="", "", D$2)`

but only the content was copied.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible using a formula. Have you tried using a script instead?

Comment: How would you do this with a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to copy an entire dropdown list into another cell using Apps Script.

Please see sample code below for fetching dropdown list as well as creating a dropdown with the fetched values from the original dropdown.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1).getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues();
  var range2 = sheet.getRange(1,2);
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(range[0]).build();
  range2.setDataValidation(rule)
}
```

With this, you can add the condition that you want before creating the dropdown copy.